# Context-sensitive braces with glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I use the glossaries package for handling my acronyms. On first use, I want the acronyms to be printed in the form "long (short)". However, it may well be that the text where an acronym is used for the first time is already embedded in parentheses, such as item 2. in the following example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Umlaute
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{nemesis}{NEMESIS}{Netherlands Mental Health Survey and Incidence Study}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

\section*{Dummy text}
\noindent \textbf{Everything is fine in a normal textenvironment:}\\
The \gls{nemesis} indicates something.\vspace{1cm}

\glsresetall

\noindent\textbf{If used first inside parentheses, the result looks ugly:}\\
Some studies' names (e.g. the \gls{nemesis}) make interesting acronyms.\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\textbf{This is what it should look like:}\\
Some studies' names (e.g. the Netherlands Mental Health Survey and Incidence Study [NEMESIS]) make interesting acronyms.

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to get glossaries to set the parentheses correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document to start with!

Comment: Thanks, I have inserted an MWE into the original posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a command that will toggle between `(` ... `)` and `[` ... `]`. This is a bit like the automated quoting system provided by packages like [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes). In general I think `csquotes` is much better than [`quotmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quotmark), but here we could hijack `quotmark` and use it for parenthetical material. That way it shouldn't interfere if you happen to need `csquotes`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quotmark}

\setquotemarks{{(}{)},{[}{]}}
\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\tqt{#1}}

\begin{document}
\paren{Some \paren{parenthetical} text}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: (Some [parenthetical] text)]

Now instead of explicitly using `(...)`, you can use `\paren{...}`. There may be other neater ways of defining `\param`, but once you've settled on your preferred definition, you need an acronym style uses this command.

The simplest approach is to use the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), but make sure you have up-to-date versions of both `glossaries` (at least v4.23) and `glossaries-extra` (at least v1.04):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{quotmark}
\setquotemarks{{(}{)},{[}{]}}
\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\tqt{#1}}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,nonumberlist,nopostdot=false]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\renewcommand*{\glsxtruserparen}[2]{%
  \glsxtrfullsep{#2}%
  \paren{#1\ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{#2}{, \glscurrentfieldvalue}{}}%
}


\newacronym{nemesis}{NEMESIS}{Netherlands Mental Health Survey and
Incidence Study}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\section*{Dummy text}
\noindent \textbf{Everything is fine in a normal textenvironment:}\\
The \gls{nemesis} indicates something.\vspace{1cm}

\glsresetall

\noindent\textbf{First use inside parentheses:}\\
Some studies' names \paren{e.g. the \gls{nemesis}} make interesting
acronyms.\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\textbf{Compare with:}\\
Some studies' names (e.g. the Netherlands Mental Health Survey and
Incidence Study [NEMESIS]) make interesting acronyms.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

If you want to just use `glossaries` without the extension package, then you need to define a custom style:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{quotmark}
\setquotemarks{{(}{)},{[}{]}}
\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\tqt{#1}}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries        

\newacronymstyle{long-paren-short}%
{%
  \ifglshaslong{\glslabel}{\glsgenacfmt}{\glsgenentryfmt}%
}%
{%
  \renewcommand*{\GenericAcronymFields}{description={\the\glslongtok}}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentrylong{##1}##2\space
   \paren{\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \Glsentrylong{##1}##2\space
   \paren{\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentrylongpl{##1}##2\space
   \paren{\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \Glsentrylongpl{##1}##2\space
   \paren{\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymentry}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}}%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymsort}[2]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\firstacronymfont}[1]{\acronymfont{##1}}%
  \renewcommand*{\acrpluralsuffix}{\glspluralsuffix}%
}

\setacronymstyle{long-paren-short}

\newacronym{nemesis}{NEMESIS}{Netherlands Mental Health Survey and
Incidence Study}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\section*{Dummy text}
\noindent \textbf{Everything is fine in a normal textenvironment:}\\
The \gls{nemesis} indicates something.\vspace{1cm}

\glsresetall

\noindent\textbf{First use inside parentheses:}\\
Some studies' names \paren{e.g. the \gls{nemesis}} make interesting
acronyms.\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\textbf{Compare with:}\\
Some studies' names (e.g. the Netherlands Mental Health Survey and
Incidence Study [NEMESIS]) make interesting acronyms.

\end{document}
```

This produces the same result.

**Edit:**

When using `\newacronymstyle` (or `\newabbreviationstyle` with `glossaries-extra`) there can be a difference between using `\glsfirst` and the first use of `\gls`. This is due to the line:

```
  \ifglshaslong{\glslabel}{\glsgenacfmt}{\glsgenentryfmt}%
```

in the acronym style (with `glossaries` or due to the redefinition of `\glsentryfmt` in `glossaries-extra`). This essentially determines if the entry is an abbreviation (has a `long` value) or if it's a normal (or regular) entry.

Both `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra` use `\glsgenentryfmt` for regular entries. This uses the value of the `first` field on first use (or the `firstplural` field on first use if `\glspl` has been used) and the value of the `text` field on subsequent use (or the `plural` field for `\glspl`). Since `\glsfirst` displays the value of the `first` field, it's the same as `\gls` on first use for regular entries.

The default definition of `\newacronym` also behaves in this way, where the `first` field is set to `\acrfullformat{`*long*`}{`*short*`}`, but this can mess up `\Gls` (if `\acrfullformat` is redefined to show the short form first) and the insert from the final optional argument of commands like `\gls` can't be treated properly.

This is why the newer ways of defining abbreviations (using `\setacronymstyle` in `glossaries` or `\newabbreviation` in `glossaries-extra`) don't use the `first` key when using `\gls` on first use. This means that commands like `\Gls` can now function correctly, but it means that `\glsfirst` is no longer appropriate for these entries. Instead you can use commands like `\acrfull` (with `glossaries`) or `\glsxtrfull` (with `glossaries-extra`) to show the full form.

If you really want to, you can modify the style to set the `first` key, as in the modified example below:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{quotmark}
\setquotemarks{{(}{)},{[}{]}}
\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\tqt{#1}}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries        

\newacronymstyle{long-paren-short}%
{%
  \ifglshaslong{\glslabel}{\glsgenacfmt}{\glsgenentryfmt}%
}%
{%
  \renewcommand*{\GenericAcronymFields}{%
    first={\the\glslongtok\space\protect\paren{\the\glsshorttok}},
    description={\the\glslongtok}}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentrylong{##1}##2\space
   \paren{\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \Glsentrylong{##1}##2\space
   \paren{\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentrylongpl{##1}##2\space
   \paren{\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \Glsentrylongpl{##1}##2\space
   \paren{\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymentry}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}}%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymsort}[2]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\firstacronymfont}[1]{\acronymfont{##1}}%
  \renewcommand*{\acrpluralsuffix}{\glspluralsuffix}%
}

\setacronymstyle{long-paren-short}

\newacronym{nemesis}{NEMESIS}{Netherlands Mental Health Survey and
Incidence Study}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

The \glsfirst{nemesis}['s] findings show that\ldots

The \acrfull{nemesis}['s] findings show that\ldots

The \gls{nemesis}['s] findings show that\ldots

\end{document}
```

Note the difference in the treatment of the optional argument.

[image: image of document with the first paragraph different from the other two]

In the case of `\glsfirst`, the `'s` is just appended after the parentheses, which looks weird, whereas with the other two cases, the `'s` has been inserted after the long form.

Comment: Sorry that I'm replying so late -- the notification mail was falsely recognizes as spam, so I didn't see it immediately.  The solution is perfect -- in fact, as user of the csquotes-package, I had already thought of doing the nesting in a csquotes-like manner, i just didn't know how to get this done.

Comment: Just for the record:
In case you write your own macros and finish them with `\xspace`, consider to insert `\qt@endquote` in `\xspaceaddexceptions`:

`\makeatletter\xspaceaddexceptions{\qt@endquote}\makeatother`

Comment: Using `\setquotemarks{{(}{)},{[}{]}}` and the `\paren`-construct works fine, but do you know how to make these changes persistent? Every time `\selectlanguage{languagename}` from babel is used in the document, `\setquotemarks{{(}{)},{[}{]}}` has to be called again, otherwise the default quotation marks instead of the parentheses will be used further on.

Comment: @Andreas Try loading `quotmark` before `babel`.

Comment: Great, that did the trick!

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but I have another problem. When I use `\glsfirst{key}` now, I don't get something like `\gls{key}` on first use, but only the short form (i.e. `\gls{key}` on subsequent use). Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Are you using `glossaries` or `glossaries-extra`?

Comment: I use `glossaries` (`\usepackage[xindy, acronym, toc, nopostdot, nogroupskip, translate=babel]{glossaries}`), with the last code from your answer.

Comment: @Andreas I've edited my answer, but basically just use `\acrfull` instead of `\glsfirst`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The new solution works as expected, so I didn't have to change all instances of `\glsfirst`in my document.